# slick carousel in infinite scroll masonry card works with the first load, but carousels does not work on the new items.

Tags: infinite-scroll, jquery-masonry

Below is the script for slick carousel.

```
    function slider () {

      var $arrows = $('.arrows');
            var $next = $arrows.children(".slick-next");    
            var $prev = $arrows.children(".slick-prev");

            var slick = $('.your-class').slick({
                appendArrows: $arrows
            });

            $('.slick-next').on('click', function (e) {
                var i = $next.index( this )
                console.log("i", i);

                slick.eq(i).slickNext();

            });
            $('.slick-prev').on('click', function (e) {
                var i = $prev.index( this )
                slick.eq(i).slickPrev();
            });   
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
      slider();
    })
</script>
```

below is the script for infinite scroll masonry

```
    <script>
$(window).load(function(){

    var $container = $('#rowmasonry');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.itemmasonry',
            fitWidth: true,
            gutter: 0,

        });
    });



    $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#page-nav',    
    nextSelector : '#page-nav a', 
    itemSelector : '.itemmasonry', 
    negativeMargin: 250,
    loading: {
    finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
    img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
    },  
    function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){  
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        });

    });

}); 

</script>
```

I am using these scripts in php. I assume that infinite scroll masonry should be destroyed and re-inited as the next items load.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `slider();` in your infinitescroll callback function:

```
$(window).load(function(){

var $container = $('#rowmasonry');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.itemmasonry',
        fitWidth: true,
        gutter: 0,

    });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
navSelector  : '#page-nav',    
nextSelector : '#page-nav a', 
itemSelector : '.itemmasonry', 
negativeMargin: 250,
loading: {
finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
}
},  
function( newElements ) {
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){  
        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
    });

 slider(); 

 });

});
```

Comment: A link would be necessary to offer any more help.